# “During first period” vs. “during the first period”

Tags: articles

Consider the following sentences, referring to a student in high school:

> Halfway through second period, he was getting tired.

vs.

> Halfway through **the** second period, he was getting tired.

Is “the” before “second period” necessary or preferred here? Is it a matter of formal vs. colloquial writing?

The question “[‘During summer’ vs. ‘during the summer’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37738/during-summer-vs-during-the-summer)” appears related, but its two answers disagree with one another and I’m not sure which one applies to my case, if either.

Comment: 'Period' is a countable noun, but in your context 'summer' an uncountable noun.

Comment: *Pupils* (and to a lesser extent, *teachers*) might sometimes omit the article before nouns like ***first period, lunch break*** because the specific referents are obvious / very familiar ***in context***. But if you're talking to someone who *doesn't* spend a large part of their day dealing with such nouns, you should always include the articles. Not using the articles when you're interacting with people outside the "special domain" (school) makes you sound "parochial" (you live in your own small world, and don't get out much to hear how others talk! :)

Comment: "In first period" means a specific portion of the school day, but "in the first period" doesn't have that specific meaning. I hardly consider it parochial to use the correct terminology.

Comment: Every school has its own characteristic speech pattern. Go there and see what the students say; there is no general rule.

Comment: At every school I've been to, we said "Nth period" with no article, although they were all in close geographic proximity so it could have been regional. But I've also heard this use in many TV shows and movies set all over the US. Do you have counterexamples? @JohnLawler

Comment: My understanding is that we omit the article because we use "Nth period" as a *name* for that segment of the school schedule.

Comment: It's common, but _period_ is not the only word used. In the US, there is **no** national standard for schools, and each cherishes their own traditions, just like their sports teams.

Comment: Anybody any clue why this was considered ELL not ELU? It always seems they're a bit quick to get rid of questions they don't like. This one, tbh, boils down to "Which school are you talking about & in what country?" There is no hard & fast rule. My own English Grammar school wouldn't ever use 'the'. Someone else's might have.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I agree it was transitioned too hastily. The implications of null article use are deep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usage is a matter of familiarity or naming, two functions that commonly allow the null article. In short, omitting the article is common for two people at school who understand that *first period* happens every day. Keeping the article makes it sound like one is speaking as or addressing an audience not from high school.

### The null article

The terminology I'm using comes from Marianne Celce-Murcia and Diane Larsen-Freeman, *[The Grammar Book](https://www.scirp.org/(S(vtj3fa45qm1ean45vvffcz55))/reference/ReferencesPapers.aspx?ReferenceID=1846441)* (1999, p. 280-81), which in turn comes from the work of [Chesterman](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/on-definiteness/70F926EDB1DD7F8572E57A0567819D56) (1991) and Master (1997 conference talk; [fuller findings published in 2003](https://escholarship.org/content/qt2kb4p9r0/qt2kb4p9r0.pdf?t=lb7ioa)). In trying to identify situations where an article is omitted, they find two common situations: where the article would otherwise be *a/an* and where the article would otherwise be *the*. In other words, the article is omitted in either very *indefinite* situations (called the *zero article*) or very *definite* situations (called the *null article*):

[image]

The Master (2003) article provides several examples of null articles, or ones that are very definite and that the audience and user know beforehand. In other words, omitting the article shows a lot of familiarity with the noun. This especially happens for proper nouns (we don't say "the Italy") but can also happen for some common nouns if the reference in context is explicit:

> Mr. Jones was appointed chairman. (Situation where members of the organization know already that "chairman" is a single, definite position; *the chairman* or *the head officer* would be alternatives)

> After dinner we'll see a movie. (Situation where "dinner" is a time that is routine for everyone involved; *the dinner* or *the meal* might be alternatives)

### Null articles at school

Organizations can develop specific patterns of null article use around routine times of day, positions, or other familiar noun phrases. Exact use can vary from school to school. For instance, in many schools it is common to omit the article when referring to

- routinized periods of time ("Did you go to first period?" Compare "the first period.")
- regular courses one attends ("I didn't see you in math class." Compare "the math class.")
- some direct titles, like in sports ("Coach pulled me out of class." Compare "the coach."

Adding the article can change definiteness. So "Did you go to the first period" might be something said to a new student or by someone outside of that routine time structure, for whom the sense of "first period" is just a little less definite. The same is true of your example: "Halfway through the second period, he was getting tired" sounds like it is spoken to outsiders, that is, the audience may understand that high school has periods of time for class but not necessarily know that it is called "second period."

That said, adding the article can also change other qualities. For instance, compare these two statements:

> We'll meet in gym.

> We'll meet in the gym.

For a schoolgoer in the US, "We'll meet in gym" is understood as *the gym class*, whereas "We'll meet in the gym" is understood as *the gymnasium*, that is, the space.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of *naming* the learning periods of the day you don't use articles.  "I have maths in second period"  You would only use "the" in a longer expression like "the second period of the school day".  Similarly words like "break" or "lunch" are used without articles: "Break is a 10:20".

The usage of "period" will vary from one school to another. Some schools will talk about "second lesson" or have some other term, and of course the start and end times of second lesson will vary from school to school.

Comment: Not just learning periods, at least not in the US, where we'd say things like, "Break is at 9:15 and lunch is 12:30"